# assigned twice on const char*

Tags: c++

```
const char* str ="Hello World!"
str = "HELLO!"
```

In this code, will the string "Hello World!" be erased from memory or will it be left alone?

Comment: [Have you checked](https://godbolt.org/z/Pj1v5KcK7) whether that code compiles?

Comment: From a standard perspective, string literals have static storage duration (which means they exist throughout program execution) and cannot be modified by a program that has no diagnosable errors and does not have undefined behaviour.   Of course, there is also the "what if" rule - which means that, in your code, the literal "Hello World!" can be optimised out of existence - which says that any transformations are possible, as long as observable behaviour (i.e. output) is unchanged.

Comment: @DrewDormann - The code (assuming they are two consecutive lines in a function, and semi-colons are placed at the end of each line) has no diagnosable errors.    `str` is a pointer to `const char`, so can be reassigned (but `str` cannot be used to change the data that `str` points at - e.g. it cannot be used to overwrite a string literal).

Comment: @Peter -- just so you don't start a trend, the "what if" rule is actually the "as if" rule. <g>

Comment: Thanks @PeteBecker - I wasn't trying to start a trend.   Simply typed too fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not specified by the C++ standard. Your compiler can do whatever it wishes here, including not even storing the original string in the first place, and effectively compiling the following code only:

```
const char* str = "HELLO!"
```

Your compiler can prove that performing this optimization has no observable effects, and the C++ standard allows C++ compilers to implement any optimization that has no observable effects.

So what happens here depends entirely on your C++ compiler.

Comment: Perhaps germaine to the asker - reassigning a pointer does _not_ observably free the previous data.  That's why the compiler has flexibility regarding what happens.

Answer (score 2):

In general, string constants tend to be in the global data section, and aren't "freed" until the program ends.

You can see this here: https://godbolt.org/z/a3TbjTba1

String literals, according to `[lex.string]/14` are:

> Evaluating a string-literal results in a string literal object with static storage duration, initialized from the
> given characters as specified above